# Fonts and layout problems after start Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, fonts, layout

I have a problem with layouts in Ubuntu. I am getting fonts and layouts like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

This problem occurs only after shutdown and start. After restart from shutdown menu everything is alright.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you would expect it to look like? As there are various themes and fonts out there that you might have set, I can't tell what is wrong on the images. It looks to me as if your gtk+ theme was set to one from the last century, though.

Comment: I cannot add more links to question. Alright layout is here http://imgur.com/a/duP0U . Fonts little thicker and layout completely diffrent.

Comment: are there any errors in ~/.xsession-errors when the theme is broken? and another question: are you per chance running the system from a ssd and your home on a hdd?

Comment: Only error i have regardless of broken start or not is: 
openConnection: connect: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
cannot connect to brltty at :0

Comment: I have SSD and HDD but all ubuntu files are on SSD.  
HDD is not reachable from ubuntu almost all the time. (Because of fast start of Windows on HDD)

Comment: I, too, got the error regarding the brltty in my .xsession-errors file. That would be because I do not own a braille display. Anyway: I'm clueless where to continue the search.

Comment: What is the program you were using at the second screenshot? Do you mean if you restart, it is all OK but if you do shutdown and start, it is causing this problem?

Comment: Program on second picture is Geany. Start and restart: yes. Whole system.

Comment: Me too facing exactly similar issue. Running on Lenovo Z510. I am wondering if it might be because I am using default graphics driver for Nvidia card?